# Не рендерится destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', dog %></td>  
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_dog_path(dog) %></td>  
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', dog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

def destroy  
  @dog.destroy  
  respond_to do |format|  
    format.html { redirect_to dogs_url, notice: 'Dog was successfully destroyed.' }  
    format.json { head :no_content }  
  end  
end
```

Код сгенерирован с помощью команды `rails generate scaffold Dog name:string`
При нажатии на `Destroy` просто открывается страница пёсика. 
Как пофиксить и почему это перестало работать?

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не указан путь. Для `edit` указан, а для `destroy` - нет

Попробуйте так:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', dog_path(dog), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

P.S. Хотя, скорее всего, дело не в этом.
Мне кажется, что у вас библиотека `jquery-ujs` либо не подключена, либо подключена, но не навешивает обработчик на ссылку.
А ссылка на удаление у вас динамически рисуется на клиенте?

Comment: Не, так всё равно просто открывает страницу собаки. Как при клике на `Show`.

Comment: @AnnDart я дополнил ответ

Comment: @AnnDart в `app/assets/javascript/application.js` есть строка `//= require jquery_ujs`?

Comment: Да, есть. Её необходимо раскомментить?

Comment: @AnnDart выложите ваш `app/assets/javascript/application.js` в вопрос

Comment: Готово.
У меня ещё вылазит ошибка на строку `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`, когда у меня закомменчена та строка.
Ошибка:
`ExecJS::ProgramError in Dogs#index`  
`TypeError: Объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод`

Comment: @AnnDart для того, чтобы ссылки на удаление работали строка ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ ЗАКОММЕНТИРОВАНА. `//= require jquery_ujs` - эта строка говорит "вставь библиотеку jquery_ujs". А вы, под какой системой запускаете приложение?

Comment: Под виндой.
Под убунту всё чудесно работало :(

Comment: @AnnDart а гемы все нормально поставились?

Comment: Вроде да. Всё спокойно поставилось, после не долгой пляски с бубнами.

Comment: @AnnDart надо гуглить на тему "ruby windows execjs error". Я когда-то ставил, на винду, но уже не помню как это делается.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решила установка Node.js и перезапуск терминала.