# Не работает экшн delete с хелпером link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ситуация такая, у меня есть контроллер `Student` со стандартными `CRUD` экшенами, которые работают через линки `create, show, edit` но экшн `destroy`

```
def destroy
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @student.destroy

    redirect_to students_path
  end
```

не хочет работать, при нажатии на ссылку ведет на show при этом игнорирует `delete` и `confirm`. Линка на вьюхе:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Удалить', student,
        method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Нашел, как я считаю, костыль, вместо хелпера `link_to` использовать `buttom_to`, но и тут не все так гладко - удаления работает при этом не выскакивает подтверждения (джава в браузере включена). Из того что я [нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934196/rails-3-link-to-delete-is-redirecting-to-show-action-with-jquery-installed), немного понятно что это `jquery` по каким-то соображениям безопасности не дает использовать линку для удаления. Хотелось бы чтобы все-таки работало через линк, а не кнопку, ну и само собой чтобы "всплывало" подтверждение. Заранее спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: [Похожая проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471257/181100), с поправкой лишь на то, что начиная с Rails 5.1.0 вместо `jquery_ujs` ввели `rails-ujs`. Настолько новые версии Rails я пока не щупал, поэтому не могу дать точных инструкций по проверке и устранению. Но симптом указывает на проблему именно с этим.

Comment: Судя по логам не подключилась библиотека `jquery` поскольку возникает ошибка `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`, сделал как написано [тут](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/924) но не помогло, как еще можно решить проблему с подключениям библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

В шаблоне вам необходимо включить JavaScript:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```